# Can the "main" function be declared with the "noexcept" specifier?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, program-entry-point, c++17, noexcept

Is the following code valid in C++?

```
int main() noexcept
{
}
```

Both *clang++ 3.8.0* and *g++ 7.2.0* [compile it fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/358ca47b06c9f32b) (with `-std=c++14 -O0 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic-errors` compilation flags).

Is it allowed to use complex conditions (e.g. including `noexcept` operator) in the `noexcept` specification of the `main` function?

And what about C++17? As I know `noexcept` specifier becomes the part of the function type in this revision of the standard.

Comment: I cannot find anything about the main function concerning noexcept in the Standard, implying it's allowed, but then again I'm drunk, so hopefully someone will join in.

Comment: What exactly would it matter? If an exception escapes `main`, `std::terminate` must be called. If an exception exits a `noexcept` function, `std::terminate` must be called. For all useful purposes, `main` *already is* `noexcept`. And since you can neither call `main` nor get a pointer to it... what does it matter?

Comment: @NicolBolas Interesting note. I thought I could find an example of the code where throwing `int main()` and `int main() noexcept` give different results but I can't do it quickly. Possibly you are right and there is no such example at all.

Comment: @Constructor: There is one difference. If you try to throw though a `noexcept` function, then stack unwinding *never* occurs. Whereas if you attempt to throw through `main`, stack unwinding *might* occur; it's implementation-dependent.

Comment: @NicolBolas It is strange but *clang++* shows an exactly opposite behavior: it looks like [with `noexcept` it does stack unwinding](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d0fbcc8435872ae) and [without `noexcept` it doesn't](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/27867e535a42c178).

Comment: @Constructor That sounds like a bug more than anything else.

Comment: @NicolBolas No, in both cases whether unwinding occurs is implementation-defined.

Comment: @T.C.: Where does the standard say that? Unwinding does not happen until after a handler has been found. If `noexcept` is encountered before a handler has been found, then the standard says `std::terminate` gets called. I don't see where it allows the implementation to invoke unwinding to the `noexcept` function.

Comment: @NicolBolas [except.terminate]/2.

Answer (score 22):

The standard [**[basic.start.main]**] specifies the following constraints on the `main` function:

> An implementation shall allow both:
>
> — a function of () returning int and
>
> — a function of (int, pointer to pointer to char) returning int

Moreover:

> A program that defines main as deleted or that declares main to be inline, static, or constexpr is ill-formed.

In practice, there is no specification about `noexcept` qualifier for `main`. On the other hands, [`noexcept`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec) is allowed as a specifier for whatever function. That would imply `main noexcept` is *not* *ill-formed*.

---

### What's difference w/o `noexcept` main?

Since the standard is not very explicit about `noexcept` for `main` function as we've seen, we can try to deduct some behaviour and check the implementations.

From [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec):

> Whenever an exception is thrown and the search for a handler encounters the outermost block of a non-throwing function, the function std::terminate is called.

While the general rule for exceptions, from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw):

> If an exception is thrown and not caught, including exceptions that escape the initial function of std::thread, the main function, and the constructor or destructor of any static or thread-local objects, then std::terminate is called. It is implementation-defined whether any stack unwinding takes place for uncaught exceptions.

This implies that `throw` from `main` function *always* generates a `std::terminate` invocation. Regardless of `noexcept` specification of the `main`.

#### Implementation side:

Indeed, the following codes:

```
int main(int argc, char* argvp[]) {
  throw 1;
  return 0;
}
```

and

```
int main(int argc, char* argvp[]) noexcept {
  throw 1;
  return 0;
}
```

will produce the same output assembly. For example in [GCC](https://godbolt.org/g/AauTP2):

```
main:
        movl    $4, %edi
        subq    $8, %rsp
        call    __cxa_allocate_exception
        xorl    %edx, %edx
        movl    $1, (%rax)
        movl    typeinfo for int, %esi
        movq    %rax, %rdi
        call    __cxa_throw
```

That means it will be resolved into an invocation of `std::terminate` because the stack frame is empty at "main level" regardless of `noexcept` specification.

Comment: What about the difference between `int main() noexcept` and simple `int main()`?

Comment: @Constructor I've tried to derivated the difference in the endited answer.

Answer (score 8):

The type of `main` in  `int main() noexcept;` is "function of `()` returning `int`" in C++14 and "`noexcept` function of `()` returning `int`" in C++17.

The former is explicitly required to be supported by [basic.start.main]. The latter isn't.

This looks like a defect in C++17.

Comment: Someone who is more enthusiastic about reporting core issues than I am should contact EDG's Mike Miller, the CWG chair, so that - assuming that it hasn't been reported previously - the issue will pop up on the core issues list two years from now.

Comment: _the issue will pop up on the core issues list two years from now_ So optimistic… :D